# How do I quickly build and test the kernel if I want to modify a system call

Tags: linux, kernel

In particular, I'd like to add a fd flag and a branch in a couple of fd-handling syscalls that should be used if the flag is set instead of the current code. I think the only thing that matters here for the purposes of this question is that this should be a generic rather than hardware specific modification.

How do I set things up so that I can rebuild the modified kernel and test the new feature quickly? I figure I need a basic setup that'll boot in a virtual machine and run my test code, which I guess could be simply in initram and the boot might not need to go any further (?)

Are there any good guides on this or can you explain it in a single answer here?

Comment: Depending on the specifics, you might also look at implementing this as an `LD_PRELOAD`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`eudyptula-boot`](https://github.com/vincentbernat/eudyptula-boot) is quite handy for this; its [introductory blog post](https://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-eudyptula-boot.html) has more details, but basically it allows you to boot a VM using the kernel you wish to test, and your existing filesystems (using `overlayfs`). That way you can quickly check a kernel without rebooting, and you still have access to all your files.

The only requirement on the kernel being tested is that it support `overlayfs` and `9p`; these are easy to activate in the kernel configuration before building it.